# Deleting order does not re-adjust inventory

Tags: expresso-store

I have my products set to 'Limit Stock' and have entered stock amounts. I have processed a few test orders and then deleted them. After doing so, I noticed that the stock counts do not re-adjust accordingly -- i.e. they do not return to their previous counts.

Does deleting an order not re-adjust the inventory accordingly? I really hope this is not the case.

Comment: I think you answered your own question! You just tried it. I don't know at what moment the stuck is deducted, but probably after a payment is done. And a order with a payment should not be deleted in my opinion!

Answer (score 3):

No, deleting orders does not return the stock. You will need to adjust the stock manually in the case of a canceled/returned order.

In general you probably shouldn't delete orders anyway. For accounting purposes it is better to make a status "returned" or "canceled" to keep track of how many orders were not successful.

Comment: +1 for keeping the orders. That's how it's done.